# Slicing every item in a list

Tags: python, string, list, slice

I have a CSV file containing about 3000 rows, which I have imported into Python as a list of strings to get the following;

```
mylist = [('GA0001.abc.123',), ('GA0002.456.cba',), ('GA0003.321.abc',), ('GA0004.xyz.789',)]
```

Is there a way I can slice all of the strings to remove the last 8 characters so that the list would read as follows:

```
newlist = [('GA0001',), ('GA0002',), ('GA0003',), ('GA0004',)]
```

I have tried `[x[:-8] for x in mylist]` but that just returns `[(), (), (), ()]`

Comment: It isn't a list of strings. It's a list of tuples containing a single string each. Note the trailing comma after each string. `[x[0][:-8] for x in mylist]`

Comment: `[x[0][:-8] for x in mylist]`

Comment: @roganjosh Or just `[x[:-8] for x, in mylist]`.

Comment: Worth noting the difference here. `[x[0][:-8] for x in mylist]` will still succeed if any of the tuples have *more* than one element (silently ignoring any after the first), whereas `[x[:-8] for x, in mylist]` will raise an exception. Which of these is preferable may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your original list is a **list** of **tuples** of **strings**. The solution `[x[:-8] for x in mylist]` would work if your original list was a **list** of **strings**, but in your case, we need:

```py
mylist = [('GA0001.abc.123',), ('GA0002.456.cba',), ('GA0003.321.abc',), ('GA0004.xyz.789',)]

newlist = [x[0][:-8] for x in mylist] 

print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
['GA0001', 'GA0002', 'GA0003', 'GA0004']
```

Note `x[0][:-8]` instead of `x[:-8]`.

Comment: We don't "need" that. There are other ways. Including a shorter one.

Comment: @HeapOverflow yeah, the comma to denote a length-1 tuple will work, and save you a whole 1 character. But I don't necessarily think it's as readable, or obvious to somebody who doesn't know the syntax for defining a length-1 tuple. So "need" in this case is subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Your list consists of tuples, so you are missing and extra index.

In case you want to keep is as a tuple, try this:

```
newlist = [(x[0][:-8],) for x in mylist]
```

And if not, just ditch the internal parenthesis:

```
newlist = [x[0][:-8] for x in mylist]
```